# Sass math invalid css

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

I use the Zurb Foundation.tramide Sass framework.

When I go to compile I get this error:
error scss/node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/util/_math.scss (Line 23: Invalid CSS after " @return math": expected "}", was ".abs($a);")

Comment: Could you kindly provide your `package.json` file to help us check its versions? This will enable us to offer a more accurate answers. It's possible that you may be experiencing compatibility issues between Foundation and the SASS compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of math. is several places in the _math.scss file and in motionui